# Hex editor to translate/read doubles?

Tags: hex-editor

Is there a hex editor out there that can switch between reading hex and translating the string of bits into different standard variables such as doubles, ints, chars? (this is assuming that I know in advance that the entire file only contains a certain type of variable, ie, outputted from a program that i wrote).

Thanks,

-Faken

Comment: for what operating system? :)

Answer (score 1):

From HDD Software: [Free Hex Editor Neo](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/Products/home/hex-editor-free.html)

> Free Hex Editor Neo is award-winning large files optimized freeware editor for everyone who works with ASCII, hex, decimal, float, double and binary data.

This sounds like what you need.

Comment: Ahh, almost...It dose almost everything i want it to do except for one major flaw: it cant display ints.

Comment: Never mind, it can display ints, but only on the unlocked versions and the option was display as decimals. Id vote best answer...but i cant because for some reason my old account was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hex editors that do what you ask. Just take your pick:

[HexEdit](http://www.mitec.cz/hex.html)
[Hexplorer](http://hexplorer.sourceforge.net/)
[XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm)
[Cygnus Hex Editor free](http://www.softcircuits.com/cygnus/fe/)

Comment: For some reason, i cant get any of these programs to actually display a list of ints or doubles. All these programs have the ability to convert a single entry into a int or double but i want it to output a entire grid array just as it was arranged in my data set. Also, for some reason my account was deleted and i have absolutely no idea why, so i cant vote a best answer even if i liked...sorry.